# Compartir contenido a través de la app de Facebook si está instalada

Tags: php, javascript, html5, redes-sociales

He incluido un botón en mi web para que los usuarios puedan compartirla a través de Facebook. Esto lo consigo con un simple enlace:

```
<a class="rs-link" class="fb" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.midominio.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">
```

Y modificando las etiquetas "meta" con el contenido a compartir:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://midominio.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Mi página web" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Aquí una breve descripción de la web" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://midominio.com/images/logo.jpg" />
```

Esto hace que al compartir, se realice a través del navegador. **¿Hay alguna forma de que cuando el usuario accede a la web a través de un dispositivo móvil, se detecte si tiene la app de Facebook instalada (y esté logueado) y se realice la compartición a través de ella?**